# Display loading image and load the new page on the page linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get, load

First I want to say that my english is not so good I'm Dutch!

Anyway, I was recently on a website and when I wanted to open a new page on that site there was a loading icon ward than the content of the site and then slide off the new content was retracted and the rewritten URL.
I want to know how do I do this? The site is now closed! there I noticed a few things.

```
    pageLoad: function (after){
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        $thunderbolt.backdropContainerStatics();
        if(notifications.userLoggedIn == '') $thunderbolt.checkForWidthWhiteTop();
        $thunderbolt.openWhiteTopContainer();
        jQuery('body').append('<input type="hidden" class="pageLoadingStatics" value="loaded">');
        jQuery('.firstLoadScreen .loaderBulletcontainer').fadeOut(function(){
            jQuery('.firstLoadScreen').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                jQuery('.onloadscreenafter').fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    if($thunderbolt.welcome == true){
                        floatLoadPage('welcome');
                    }
                    notifications.start();
                });     
                jQuery('body').show(after);         
                jQuery(window).resize(function(){ 
                    if(notifications.userLoggedIn == '') $thunderbolt.checkForWidthWhiteTop(); 
                });
            });
        });
    });
},
```

OTHER CODE

```
    pageLoader: function(type){
    if(type == 'show'){
        jQuery('.individualPageloader').show();
        jQuery('.individualPageloader .insidePageLoader').animate({
            marginTop: '0px'
        }, 500);
    }else{
        jQuery('.individualPageloader .insidePageLoader').animate({
            marginTop: '-80px'
        }, 500, function(){
            jQuery('.individualPageloader').hide();
        });
    }
},

getPage: function(value){
    getPage(value);
},

getPagePost: function(value, post, action){
    getPagePost(value, post, action);
},

replacePageInfo: function(sitename, data, page){
    jQuery('html title').html(sitename + ' :: ' + data);
    window.history.pushState(sitename, sitename + ' ~ ' + data, $thunderbolt.url + '/' + page);
},
```

FUNCTIONS

```
function getPage(value){
$thunderbolt.pageLoader('show');

jQuery.post($thunderbolt.url + "/page/" + value, function(page){
    jQuery('.loadIntoContainer .loadIntoContainerInside').fadeOut(function(){
        jQuery(this).html(page).fadeIn(function(){
            $thunderbolt.pageLoader('hide');
        });
        Cufon.replace("ubuntu");
        $thunderbolt.disableImageDrag();
    });
});
```

}

function getPagePost(value, post, action){
    $thunderbolt.pageLoader('show');

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $thunderbolt.url + "/page/" + value,
    data: "" + post + "",
    success: function(page){
        jQuery('.loadIntoContainer .loadIntoContainerInside').fadeOut(function(){
            jQuery(this).html(page).fadeIn(function(){
                $thunderbolt.pageLoader('hide');
            });
            Cufon.replace("ubuntu");
            $thunderbolt.disableImageDrag();
        });
    }
});
```

}

OTHER FUNCTIONS

```
function floatLoadPage(value, after){
jQuery('.floatLoadPage').html('<div class="quickProfileLoader" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; margin: auto; margin-top: 25%;"><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-top: -20px;" src="assets/image/general/loader/loader_white.gif"></div>').fadeIn('slow');
$thunderbolt.floatBackdropClick('.floatLoadPage');

jQuery.get("../../application/pages/float/float-" + value + ".php", function(data){
    if(after == null){
        jQuery('.floatLoadPage').html(data);
    }else{
        jQuery('.floatLoadPage').html(data).fadeIn(after);
    }
    $thunderbolt.center(jQuery('.floatLoadPage .floatContainer'), 'absolute', true, '', '0', '0');
    Cufon.replace("ubuntu");
    $thunderbolt.disableImageDrag();
});
```

}

function floatLoadPagePost(value, post, action){
    jQuery('.floatLoadPage').html('').fadeIn();
    $thunderbolt.floatBackdropClick('.floatLoadPage');

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../application/pages/float/float-" + value + ".php",
    data: "" + post + "",
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('.floatLoadPage').html(data);
        $thunderbolt.center(jQuery('.floatLoadPage .floatContainer'), 'absolute', true, '', '0', '0');
        Cufon.replace("ubuntu");
        $thunderbolt.disableImageDrag();
    }
});
```

}

This was in an external. Js file

I found this among the  tags

```
<script>

                                $thunderbolt.getPage('me');
```

all pages are loaded using the following code

```
 <li onclick="$thunderbolt.getPage(&#39;radio&#39;);">
```

How do I make this code working?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry $thunderbolt was the site name!